# Threading and managed/unmanaged interop?

Tags: c#, multithreading, c++-cli, interop, com-interop

**Background**

I'm working in a project which I need to create patches to a native .exe x86 binary (compiled with microsoft's vc8 compiler - native c/c++) in order to enhance its functionality and to fix some bugs as the source code of this .exe isn't available.

Actually I make these patches in a native c++ dll which apply the patches in the code/data of that .exe as soon as it gets loaded in the executable's process memory. This approach works just fine in terms of stability, but is very messy and hard to maintain. Because of this I came up with the idea to possibly create some sort of patch engine in a native c++ dll but move all the "high-level" code to a c# dll. By "high-level" code I mean any code which isn't directly related to the patching process itself (e.g., imagine I'm creating a whole new feature for that .exe. The code related to the patching process would be in the native c++ dll, which in turns calls the respective c# functions to execute anything else).

I did some research and found that possibly the best approach for accomplishing that would be using c++/cli's "IJW" to create a bridge between that native patch engine dll and the "high-level" code in the c# dll (I need this to work in both directions. The same way I need to call c# functions from unmanaged code I will need to call unmanaged functions of both the .exe and the patch engine dll from the c# code). I also found the possibility to use COM interop but in topics around the web comparing the two approaches people states to keep with the IJW approach rather than the COM interop.

**Questions**

- Is correct to accept that the IJW approach is better than the COM interop for this specific scenario?
- Which possible problems I might experience using such IJW and COM interop approaches? My main concerns is about threading specifics; that unmanaged .exe runs its code in a single thread and I have no idea at how these patching approaches using managed code will behave related to threading - will that c# code execute in a separate thread? will the CLR creates any other thread in this process?
- Any tips or tricks about this whole idea?

Thanks in advance and feel free to share any knowledge you think might be useful about the topic.

Comment: You are trying to compare an apple and a bicycle.  IJW is very helpful to call unmanaged code from managed code, COM is the weapon of choice to call managed code from unmanaged code.  Injecting the CLR into another process that doesn't expect it or might have a dependency on the CLR as well is however a universally bad idea.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit more @HansPassant? I mean, I can imagine how foggy this may seem, but I'm really looking for to it. Considering I really want to implement that could you throw some material for me to study or just summarize what I would have to do to accomplish that? Thanks!

Comment: Also, I tried to test the COM approach yesterday and I got stuck when I called CoCreateInstance. This call seemed to block the thread and never give up, like it was in an infinite loop. I guessed it could be related to the fact I was injecting the dll which calls the COM functions, or the fact that I was calling the COM inside the DLLMain; then I moved to the IJW, which worked just fine. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: You can't call anything that can load another DLL, and especially not COM code, from DllMain().

Comment: Hi @Medinoc, could you explain why I can't do that? Any thoughts on what I could do to call the c# functions through COM in the process startup? I could delay somehow the calls to COM in order to keep outside dllmain, but it have to be executed before the main() of the patched .exe. Thanks!

Comment: You can't because loading a DLL involves acquiring a lock that doesn't support recursion, so if you do anything that loads a DLL from DllMain(), it causes a deadlock.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much @Medinoc! Which are your thoughts about using IJW anyway to do the interop in both ways? Or I really should stick with COM when interoping from unmanaged to managed? Thanks again!